# Can't show the array to charts

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax, highcharts

I got a problem using Highcharts with ajax..

I'm make a `datasource` for giving the highcharts an array..

This is the `datasource`

```
function reportPertanyaan1()
{
    $result = [];
    $this->load->model("surveymodel");
    for ($point=1; $point <=10 ; $point++) { 
        array_push($result, $this->surveymodel->GetData("1",$point));
    }

    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

And here's the ajax code that receive the array

```
$.ajax({
    url: site_url+"datasource/reportPertanyaan1",
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
        pertanyaan1(data);
    }
});
```

From the `console.log(data)`, I get this kind of array `[2,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0]`

And then, from that ajax, I call `pertanyaan1` function. This is the code

```
function pertanyaan1(jawaban){
    $('#container1').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'line'
        },
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['1', '2', '3','4', '5', '6','7', '8', '9','10']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Banyak Data'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Pertanyaan 1',
            data: jawaban
        }],
    });
}
```

And the code is not showing the chart. But it's doubled the `xAxis` label look like this

[image]

But, when I'm replace the `data: jawaban` to `data: [2,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0]`. The chart can show the data..

Any help apriciated

Comment: Have you read their documentation? Does the plugin have a place you can ask for help?

Comment: I have read it, But I can't find anything works. I've tried the `setData` but it isn't work either.. Maybe my code was wrong, can you help me to write the code that work ? thank you @evolutionxbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you are getting JSON from your ajax call. You need to define it as Js object. And don't send your data as array. Send your data as object.

Try this:

```
$data= [];
$this->load->model("surveymodel");
for ($point=1; $point <=10 ; $point++) { 
    array_push($data, $this->surveymodel->GetData("1",$point));
}

$result = new stdClass();
$result->data = $data;
echo json_encode($result);
```

And get data like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: site_url+"datasource/reportPertanyaan1",
    success: function(result){
        var resultData = JSON.parse(result);
        pertanyaan1(resultData.data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Still not showing the charts, but the `resultData` on ajax changed to this `"{\"data\":[2,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0]}"`

Comment: I get it.. I think must change the `JSON.stringify` to `JSON.parse`

Comment: @MArgusChopinGyver Yes. I changed my answer. You need to use JSON.parse.

Comment: All right. Thank you for the help @hurricane. It works !